# Reading Proc/[pid]/mem with virtual address

Tags: c, linux

If I wish to access data directly with virtual address from the other application, Can I access proc/[pid]/mem with virtual address? would the offset be the same as virtual address?

Code-wise, if I `fseeko(the-proc/[pid]/mem-File, virtual_address, SEEK_SET);`
and `fread` the amount from the virtual_address, Would I get the data from that virtual address of the application?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

/proc/[pid] is just that, it holds the process information for the given PID. Remember that each process has its own PID which is stored globally by the linux kernel.

Here's an example of how to read from proc for the statm part of proc. This code could be easily adapted to /proc/[pid]/mem according to the appropriate manpage.

```
const char *statm_path = "/proc/[pid]/statm";    

proc_f = fopen(statm_path, "r");
if (proc_f == NULL)
{
    perror("Error opening proc file");
    return;
}

// Writing the info from /proc/[pid]/statm to a struct.
if (7 != fscanf(proc_f, "%ld %ld %ld %ld %ld %ld %ld", &result.size, 
    &result.resident, &result.share, &result.text, &result.lib, 
    &result.data, &result.dt))
{
    perror(statm_path);
    return;
}
fclose(proc_f);
```

For the fields in /mem, I recommend [this page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). From here you can access any stats listed on the page. I don't think you could explicitly access particular variables or anything like that because each process has its own virtual memory space maintained individually by the kernel. At best it could get quite messy.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot exactly do that. But I believe what you are looking for is `shared memory`. Any two processes can read and write to a common memory using shared memory. The virtual addresses for this shared memory between the processes might not be same. And it has to be accessed in controlled manner by the user, no natural locking mechanism is given for that.

This [link](http://linuxgazette.net/104/ramankutty.html) from [linuxgazette](http://linuxgazette.netl) has a really good explanation with examples.